# problem sending POST request from heroku app

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to send a post request from Heroku app to another url like this:
`r = requests.post(url, data=data)`
this works on my local server so the problem is not the url or data I'm trying to send.
on heroku i get this error:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/webhook" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=32a8ec70-4ae4-4d88-b209-6b9d698df564 fwd="fwd" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-06-06T08:28:07.795046+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-06 08:28:07 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7)
2021-06-06T08:28:07.796451+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-06 08:28:07 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-06-06T08:28:07.890439+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-06 08:28:07 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
```

why is this happening? and is there an alternative?

Comment: How long does the request take to process locally?

Comment: me too , at local is fine and quick , using heroku db in the local  is also great !   but deploy to heroku app only GET request can success ...

Is there any problem here ? any suggestion